# Circular Progress Indicator not displayed when the condition is true

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:futureprovider/Employee.dart';
    import 'package:futureprovider/EmployeeService.dart';
    import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

    void main() => runApp(MyApp(
    ));

    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

      final PostService fur = PostService();

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MultiProvider(
          providers: [
            FutureProvider(create:(context)=> fur.getEmployees(),
            catchError: (context,e){
              print(e.toString());
              },
              //initialData: [Post(id:1,name: 1,title: '1',body: '1')],
            )
          ],
          child: MaterialApp(
            home: Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Posts Dashboard")),
              body:TilesOfPost(),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }

    class TilesOfPost extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {

        List<Post> posts = Provider.of<List<Post>>(context);

        print("Length:"+posts.length.toString());

        return (posts==null)? Center(child:CircularProgressIndicator()):ListView.builder(
            itemCount: posts.length,
            itemBuilder: (context,index){
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(posts[index].id.toString()),
                subtitle: Text(posts[index].name.toString())
              );
            }
        );
      }
    }
```

In the following code,
I have Future Provider which provides some future values and when i execute the code,

initially when the List is null it should show Circular Progress Widget,

but it gives an exception for the ListView being build with length null.

How do i show Circular Progress Inidcator when the Future value is still not received

Comment: I think the posts are not null. I recommend you to log your posts list. it will show what gonna happened.

Comment: can you check using following condition (posts.length==0 || )?

Comment: @VirenVVarasadiya :I have tried using both post==null and post.length==0 but it gives the same error , and there is no problem in the data,the list is displayed properly after few seconds,just that it gives an exception of null before it retrieves the actual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **print statement** is the actual problem. when data is null then also it check for length, so i throws error because of that you are also not able to see CircularProgressIndicator().